# Laravel reorganising a RESTful API

Tags: php, rest, laravel

In a Laravel project I have a RESTful API that has been poorly organised. I wish to reorganise this, and I intend to update all current references to the API, but there is a chance that I will miss some things, or other branches when merged in may be broken. Therefore, ideally the pages I move I would like to still work (until I am confident we can remove them) but throw a warning to the logs stating that it is a deprecated URL and to update the code to use the new one. There are about 20 pages I am moving.

What would be the easiest way to implement this? One way would be to make 20 more functions that are just:

```
function a() {
    Log::warning("This is an old method blah blah blah");
    aNew();
}
```

But this seems like a very messy way to do so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a filter and just add it to the `before` key on all your routes that you are phasing out.

```
Route::get('old_api_function', array('uses' => 'ApiController@oldFunction', 'before' => 'old_api'));

Route::filter('old_api', function($route, $request, $value)
{
    Log::warning("This is an old method blah blah blah: ".$route);
});
```

And this should log the route that you want to phase out.